# Enabling custom content entity module throws error

Tags: 8, entities, drush

While enabling my custom module that creates a custom content entity through Drush, I get the following error:

> [error]  Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   Error: Declaration of Drupal\staff_profile\Entity\StaffProfile::preCreate() must be compatible with Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface::preCreate(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface $storage, array &$values) in /Users/user/Sites/drupal8staff/web/modules/custom/staff_profile/src/Entity/StaffProfile.php, line 54

Line 54 corresponds to the class StaffProfile in the following:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\staff_profile\Entity;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;
use Druapl\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
use Drupal\staff_profile\StaffProfileInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedTrait;

/**
 * Defines staff_profile entity class
 *
 *  @ingroup staff_profile
 *  @ContentEntityType(
 *    id = "staff_profile_profile",
 *    label = @Translation("Staff Profile"),
 *    handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\content_entity_example\Entity\Controller\StaffProfileListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "add" = "Drupal\content_entity_example\Form\StaffProfileForm",
  *       "edit" = "Drupal\content_entity_example\Form\StaffProfileForm",
  *       "delete" = "Drupal\content_entity_example\Form\StaffProfileDeleteForm",
  *     },
  *     "access" = "Drupal\content_entity_example\StaffProfileAccessControlHandler",
  *   },
  *    base_table = "staff_profile_entity",
  *    admin_permission = "administer staff profile entity",
  *    fieldable = TRUE,
  *    links = {
  *      "canonical" = "/people/{staff_profile_profile}",
  *      "add-page" = "/people/add",
  *      "edit-form" = "/people/{staff_profile_profile}/edit",
  *      "delete-form" = "/people/{staff_profile_profile}/delete",
  *      "collection" = "/people/list",
  *    },
  *    entity_keys = {
  *      "id" = "id",
  *      "uuid" = "uuid",
  *      "label" = "usernme",
  *      "published" = "status",
  *    },
  *    field_ui_base_route = "staff_profile.staff_profile_settings",
  *  )
  *
 */
 class StaffProfile extends ContentEntityBase implements StaffProfileInterface, EntityPublishedInterface {
   use EntityChangedTrait;

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * Set computed fields when creating a new Staff Profile
   */
   public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage, array &$values) {
     parent::preCreate($storage, $values);
     $values += array(
       'user_id' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
     );

// Methods omitted for brevity

   }

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Creates Fields and properties
   * Defines gui behavior
   */
   public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
     $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
       ->setLabel(t('ID'))
       ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

     $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
       ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
       ->setReadOnly(TRUE);


 //Fields omitted for brevity


      $fields['user_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
          ->setLabel(t('User Name'))
          ->setSettings(array(
            'target_type' => 'user',
            'handler' => 'default',
          ))
          ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'hidden',
            'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
            'weight' => -3,
          ))
          ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
            'settings' => array(
              'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
              'size' => 60,
              'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
              'placeholder' => '',                 ),
          ))
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
      }
  }
```

StaffProfileInterface.php contents:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\staff_profile;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\user\EntityOwnerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedInterface;

/**
 * Provides an interface defining a StaffProfile entity.
 * @ingroup staff_profile
 *
 */

interface StaffProfileInterface extends ContentEntityInterface, EntityOwnerInterface, EntityChangedInterface {
}
```

The preCreate method is the exact same as what can be found on the example for content entities in the Drupal 8 entity API Docs. I was able to successfully install a copy of the example content entity, but not my entity. The example entity requires the examples module, is there something in that module that I am missing in mine or was this caused by an error in my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this statement:

```
use Druapl\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
```

Drupal is spelled incorrectly.  Thus it's not using the correct class in the type hint and thinking it's an incorrect implementation